# Delete from table B where column value like table a with wildcards

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery, left-join, sql-delete

So I have two tables

```
seeds
- id
- domain

subdomain
- id 
- domain
- ip
```

I want to filter the subdomains against the domains

for example

```
seeds
Id  Domain
0   google.com
1   test.com

subdomain
Id   domain          ip
0    test.google.com    null
1    api.google.com     null
2    dnr.com            null
3    neverssl.com       null
```

I'm trying to write a single query that deletes the rows in `subdomain` that don't contain a `domain` from `seeds`

> What have you tried?

```
delete subdomain 
where id not in 
(select subs.id from seed as seeds 
join 
subdomain as subs on subs.domain 
like concat('%', seeds.domain));
```

and

```
delete subdomain 
where id not in
(SELECT sd.id
FROM subdomain sd
LEFT JOIN seed s
  ON sd.domain LIKE CONCAT('%', s.Domain)
WHERE s.id IS NULL)
```

both of these queries just delete all of the rows

Comment: So shouldn't it be `subs.subdomain` instead of `subs.domain`?

Comment: The real tables both have id,domain as their columns, I was trying to make it more clear for the question so I changed table b to subdomain

Comment: Sorry, it doesn't make it more clear if the query doesn't match the sample data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `not exists`:

```
delete from subdomain
where not exists (
    select 1
    from seeds s
    where subdomain.domain like concat('%', s.domain)
)
```

[DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/38ebab/1)

Comment: this deleted all rows

Comment: (I can restore it just wanted to let you know it didn't work lol)

Comment: @AnthonyRussell: I just updated the query to match the new table names, since you changed them in the question. This sould do what you want.

Comment: yeah I accounted for the changed table names. I'm not sure why this isn't working

Comment: Does it make a difference that id is a primary key? I see it working in your example but when I use it in my db it deletes everything

Comment: @AnthonyRussell: the query does not uses column `id` at all. Maybe your structure, or your data, is not exactly as you showed in the question.

Comment: Maybe I'm building it wrong? https://i.imgur.com/kLlAq0u.png

Comment: Does it matter that my column is TEXT?

Comment: Ahhh okay I got it, my sql script was sneaking in an extra set of quotes around the domain which was causing none of them to match I guess, so they were all getting deleted

Answer (score 1):

Use the `LEFT JOIN` + `NULL` pattern to find rows that don't match.

```
DELETE d
FROM subdomain AS d
LEFT JOIN seeds AS s ON d.domain LIKE CONCAT('%', s.domain)
WHERE s.id IS NULL
```

[DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/056b59/1)